# Defined X axis value for Multi box plot

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to get my X axis value labeled as "TDN", "DIN", "PN","TDP","SRP","PP","PN","PN.PP","TDN.TDP" instead of 1 to 8 which is done by R. I don't know how to define it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is what I created:

```
par(mfrow= c (1,8), mar = c(5,4,2,1))
boxplot(WQ.flow$TDN, WQ.flow$DIN, WQ.flow$PN, WQ.flow$TDP, WQ.flow$SRP, 
WQ.flow$PP, WQ.flow$PN.PP, WQ.flow$TDN.TDP)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just specify the `names` parameter as in:

```
boxplot(WQ.flow$TDN, 
        WQ.flow$DIN,
        WQ.flow$PN,
        WQ.flow$TDP,
        WQ.flow$SRP,
        WQ.flow$PP,
        WQ.flow$PN.PP,
        WQ.flow$TDN.TDP,
        names = c("TDN", "DIN", "PN","TDP","SRP","PP","PN","PN.PP","TDN.TDP"))
```